# Obtengo un error de Casteo cuando intento darle un color de fondo a cada una de mis ventanas en XAML con xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xaml

Actualmente quiero que cada una de las ventanas tenga una NavigationPage con un color de fondo diferente.

Este es el código que pongo en cada ventana.

```
 ((NavigationPage)App.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
```

Pero cada vez que lo correo me sale el siguiente error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Answer (score 0):

tienes que usar NavigationPage

```
var navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
```

y luego puedes aplicarle el color

```
navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
```

Comment: me dice : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'